# Install OpenCV in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV in CentOS 6. When I run the command

```
[root@cosmas opt]# sudo yum install libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev
```

it returned the follow:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * rpmforge: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
Setting up Install Process
No package libtiff4-dev available.
No package libjpeg-dev available.
No package libjasper-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://github.com/supermasita/ufe/wiki/Installing-FFMPEG-on-CentOS-with-ATRPMS-repo I just try that.. and it works..

Answer (score 13):

I just did the same install on CentOS 6.  Since the [install instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) are more geared toward Ubuntu, here is what I was able to do to install it:

1. install all the required packages using yum

   ```
   yum groupinstall "Development Tools" 
   yum install gcc 
   yum install cmake 
   yum install git
   yum install gtk2-devel
   yum install pkgconfig 
   yum install numpy 
   yum install ffmpeg
   ```
2. Create working directory and check out the source code [note: You probably don't want to use the tag below anymore as it is a significantly old version. I had to use that version due to my software requiring it.]

   ```
   mkdir /opt/working
   cd /opt/working
   git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
   cd opencv
   git checkout tags/2.4.8.2
   ```
3. Create the Makefile

   ```
   mkdir release
   cd release
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
   ```
4. If using cmake version 2.6-patch 4 (check with cmake --version), then you'll need to comment out a line in the build. Comment out string(MD5 hash "${lines}") on line 50 in /opt/working/opencv/cmake/cl2cpp.cmake. Other options (including updating cmake) can be found at [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24095/building-opencv-247-on-centos-6/).
5. Build and install

   ```
   cd /opt/working/opencv/release
   make
   make install
   ```

Comment: I tried to install opencv in Centos 6.3 . But  still I am getting error message for `ImportError: No module named cv2` . Do I need install some additional package for cv2?

Comment: Thanks. Instructions worked fine on Centos 7.3. 
Step 4 above was not needed.

Comment: will this install ffpmeg because it doesn't do so for me?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo yum search all --enablerepo=epel libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev`

Gives-

```
libjpeg-devel.x86_64 : Development tools for programs which will use the libjpeg library
Warning: No matches found for: libtiff4-dev
Warning: No matches found for: libjasper-dev
```

Which makes me think that you have wrong package names. Are you sure that these aren't debian package names?

Anyways in the meanwhile you can install `libjpeg-devel.x86_64` via-

`sudo yum install --enablerepo=epel libjpeg-dev`

Answer (score 1):

@Roopendra I met this error too and I tried: 
`cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
and solved it. Source: http://techieroop.com/install-opencv-in-centos/